# How to check if a string is in a csv header

Tags: python, csv

I have this function:

```
def check_csv(final_word):
    with open("directory\\trap_words.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for i in reader:
            str(i)

            if final_word in i:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

To check if the parameter final_word is in a csv file
But it does not return true even if the string is the same as one of the words in the csv file
This is the csv file:
[image]

Comment: what is inside `i`?

Comment: you're returning on first iteration of the loop. Perhaps, you need to move `return False` out of the loop

Comment: just words, no sentences or anything like that

when i run a loop to print the items in this csv i get ['word1'], ['word2']...etc

so im thinking that is somehow the problem

Comment: yes its the else statement that is messing it up, thank you, if you want you can post this as the answer and ill check mark it

Comment: The title says you only want to check the CSV header, which is the first row with all the field names. If that's really what you want, this code should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function loops through each line in the CSV file. On the first iteration (the first line) it checks `if final_word in i:` and then either returns back to the function caller `true` or `false` and then exits

I think the miss here is understanding that a `return` is the end of the logic, even inside a loop. Once a function returns, it stops processing.

So your code never gets past the first line of the csv. A fix is to get rid of the else and unindent `return False` to be outside of the loop and rerun

```
def check_csv(final_word):
    with open("directory\\trap_words.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for i in reader:
            str(i)

            if final_word in i:
                return True
        #only return false if we didn't already return true    
        return False
```